# transformation with mvtnorm

Tags: r, multivariate-normal-distribution

I'm struggling to understand why the following R outputs don't yield the same value.

```
require(mvtnorm)
require(expm)

set.seed(123)
d <- 10
mu <- rnorm(d)
Sig <- tcrossprod(rep(1, d)) + 3 * diag(rep(1,d))

mvtnorm::pmvnorm(upper = rep(0, d), mean = mu, sigma = Sig)

[1] 0.01361526
attr(,"error")
[1] 4.808363e-06
attr(,"msg")
[1] "Normal Completion"

mvtnorm::pmvnorm(upper = as.numeric(-solve(sqrtm(Sig)) %*% mu))

[1] 0.000336981
attr(,"error")
[1] 0
attr(,"msg")
[1] "Normal Completion"
```

In other words, I would like to compute $P(X < 0)$
where $X$ is a $d$-dimensional Gaussian random vector, $X \sim \mathcal{N}_d(\mu, \Sigma)$, by introducing the standard normal random vector $Y = \Sigma^{-1/2} \left(X - \mu\right)$, so that
$$P(X < 0) = \Phi_d\left(-\Sigma^{-1/2}\mu\right),$$
where $\Phi_d\left(\cdot\right)$ is the standard multivariate normal cumulative distribution.

Shouldn't this correspond to a plain linear transformation for the multivariate normal distribution..? I'm obviously missing something....

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Could you describe in words (or in mathematical formulas) what you are trying to achieve? Posting the raw code has two pitfalls: (1) not everyone knows R; (2) you mix theory with implementation, and those are often two different things.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've now edited my question accordingly.

Comment: The event $\cup_{i=1}^d X_i<0$ is different from the event $\cup_{i=1}^d Y_i<0$ since your transformation involves rotation of the coordinate system.

Comment: Oh I see.. Thanks for your reply. Well my goal was to involve only univariate normal distribution functions, so that I could see this as a system that I could easily solve for $\mu$ (even numerically if necessary). Do you think a simple expression is still possible?

Comment: @user79097 No, I don't think a simple expression is possible but you compute this and solve numerically for $\mu$, perhaps using `rootSolve::multiroot` or `uniroot`.